# Motherboard not POSTing: ASUS Crossblade Ranger, Q-code 00

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, post

I've been using this computer with a ASUS Crossblade Ranger for the past year. Seemed to work great for a while, but POST times have become exponentially slower over the past few weeks.

Everyday I'd go to  hit the power button, the case lights for flash on for a brief second, totally power off for another brief second, then back on, and continue booting. I'd then be greeted with a BIOS message reading something along the lines of "we shut down your computer to protect it after a power surge was detected, hit F1 to run setup." (Possibly failing PSU?) In this state, I can simply enter, then exit Setup and boot into the OS like nothing happened.

Now I'm at the point where I can't actually POST at all. The symptoms are:

- All case lights are on, all fans spinning
- Monitors, although powered, aren't receiving any signal
- The boot LEDs (e.g. CPU_LED, etc) never flash like they normally do while POSTing
- Q-Code display reads "00" which reads in the manual as "Not Used"
- When holding the power button down in this state, the computer does not respond & shut down
- No changes in hardware recently, GPU was changed out about 4 months ago
- Quick boot is enabled in BIOS, and a minimal set of devices are set to power during boot
- Occasionally, after several minutes, it spontaneously recovers from this limbo state and POSTs

I've tried:

- Pulling memory sticks (in case of faulty memory)
- Pulling GPU, using onboard graphics instead
- Inspecting the board for blow capacitors or burn marks (found none)

...I'm not even sure where else to be looking. This is a system that is otherwise stable (never crashes or freezes) if it gets past POST. I don't want to buy a new PSU until I know it's the problem. Could the motherboard gone bad? Any suggestions would be super helpful, thanks!

EDIT: Bought a new PSU... will see if that's the issue.

Comment: You have a motherboard with power supply surge detection. A friend has one, and a failing PSU triggered that error. In his case, it was only while doing intensive stuff like gaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to believe the *"we shut down your computer to protect it after a power surge was detected, hit F1 to run setup"* message, because it meant I'd have to dish out a couple hundred bucks for a new PSU... but that's exactly what I had to do. Everything is humming along normally after swapping out the old PSU for a new one.